# jquery find link that has the same ID value than the CLASS value of another element

Tags: jquery

```
var currentId = $('#nav a').attr('id');
var currentClass = $('#circle-inner h1').attr('class');
if(currentClass == currentId) {
  $('#nav a').addClass("current");
}
```

i want to compare the two valuesand if they are the same do something (addClass)

that is what i'm trying to achieve with that piece of code...

i cannot give the value of the class. there are too many.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `#circle-inner h1` only have one class?

```
var currentClass = $('#circle-inner h1').attr('class');
$("#nav a#" + currentClass).addClass("current");
```

or if the `h1` has more than one class, or to reverse the check try:

```
  $("#nav a").each(function (i) {
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('#circle-inner h1').hasClass(currentId)) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you element has more than one class use hasClass method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct equality try a RegExp test instead:

```
var currentId = $('#nav a').attr('id');
var currentClass = $('#circle-inner h1').attr('class');
if(new RegExp(currentClass).test(currentId)) {
  $('#nav a').addClass("current");
}
```